# Android: Respect in-app purchase in a different app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I would like to respect Google Play purchases made by my user in an existing released app of mine in a new app. I see no simple way in the documentation to do this, so wanted to know if there was some work-around.

Customers have already made purchases with the old app, and I don't want to make them have to buy the same content in the new app.